# Hibernate Lock table

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, seam

Seam 2.2 , Jboss 6.1, hibernate 3.5.6  and MSQL Server 2008

and have a function like this.

```
public void deliverFile() {
    EntityManager jobbEntityManager = (EntityManager)Component.getInstance("jobbEntityManager");

    JobbStatusInterface jobbStatus = new JobbStatus();
    jobbStatus.setStatus(PluginStatus.INITIATED);
    jobbEntityManager.persist(jobbStatus);


            /**

                 Code here to save a file that takes a minutes
             **/





    jobbStatus.setStatus(PluginStatus.DONE);
    jobbEntityManager.flush();





    }
    public void checkJobb(){
    EntityManager jobbEntityManager =  (EntityManager)Component.getInstance("jobbEntityManager");

        jobbEntityManager.createQuery("from JobbStatus", JobbStatus.class).getResultList();


    }
```

i have a poll on checkJobb every 10 seconds so if the deliveryFile() function is executed.

the checkJobb queues upp and stops at the query, so when deliveryFile() functions finishes it finish all 6 checkJobbs() at once.

Even if i select from the database directly it is locked and finishes it's query after deliveryFile() is done.

Is there anyway to solove this so i can do my checkJobb() while deliveryFile is executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT instead to normal READ_COMMITTED isolation.

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON; 
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET MULTI_USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve using the above code. If you want to check whether a job is initiated by loading the job status in-between..it may not be possible. Since the data is not committed yet and you are using a different session in the other function..you may not be able to see the data.

Only  the last value of the status will be committed to the database.

Comment: i want to be able to to a select to the database while the deliverFile() function is running, but it is locking the database so i can't do any queries at all. they are suspended until deliverFile is finished.